# while i use for loop to display all images on label of tkinter.The problem is it shows only one picture.but i want all

Tags: python, image, loops, tkinter, canvas

I fetch all the names of photos from the database. How to display all photos on the label?

## Here is my code:

```
photo displaying.
       for row in rows:
            photo=row[2]
            img1="images/"+str(photo)+".png"
            img= PhotoImage(file=img1)
            photol= Label(photoframe,image=img,width=150,height=100)
            photol.pack()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

You re-use the name `img` for every new image. When the loop exits all references to images except for the last one will be lost.

You can save a reference to the image in a label in the label object:

```
img = PhotoImage(file=img1)
photol = Label(photoframe, image=img, width=150, height=100)
photol.image = img   # Save reference to image within label
etc...
```